# How to get array attribute value in drop down menu in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, collections, dropdown

I am currently having a data structure as following:

```php
$data = array(
  array("111", "camera", "blue",  2000),
  array("222", "shirt",  "black", 4000),
  array("333", "top",    "red",   2500),
  array("444", "basket", "pink",  3000)
);
```

How can I get color values in a dropdown (using `select` html tag)?

Comment: # Some collection data (id, name, colour, price)

$data = array (
   array ("111", "camera", "blue",2000),
   array ("222", "shirt", "black",4000),
   array ("333", "top", "red", 2500),
   array ("444", "basket", "pink", 3000));

?>
<form>
<p>
      <label>color pickup</label>
      <input type="text" name="color" />
      <select name="town1">
            <? foreach ($data as $key =>$value) { ?>
            <option value="<? echo($key); ?>"><? echo($key); ?></option>
            <? ;} ?>           
        </select>
    </p>

Comment: The question is not understandable.

Comment: Please add a problem statement, your current progress with code, desired output and actual output to the question.

Comment: @ShwetaSubhashKadam Please don't post large chunks of code in comments. If you wish to amend your question, please edit it and add the code there. That being said, your loop looks basically ok.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the code from your comment, this should do the trick:

```
<?php
# Some collection data (id, name, colour, price)
$data = array (
    array ("111", "camera", "blue", 2000),
    array ("222", "shirt", "black", 4000),
    array ("333", "top", "red", 2500),
    array ("444", "basket", "pink", 3000)
);?>

<form>
  <p>
    <label>color pickup</label>
    <input type="text" name="color" /> 
    <select name="town1">
    <?php foreach ($data as $product) { ?> 
      <option value="<?php echo($product[2]); ?>"><?php echo($product[2]); ?></option>
    <?php ;} ?> 
    </select> 
  </p>
</form>
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/GMb7X

You were almost there. Your product arrays aren't associative arrays but simple indexed arrays, so there's no use for `=> $value`.

Just step into the multidimensional array with `foreach ($data as $product)`, and then select the desired key by its index in the $product array (in this case it's 2 for the color as index starts at 0).

So here it's `$product[2]`.

By the way, make sure you start php tags with `<?php`, not just `<?`.